# Fetching graph data using ajax in React JS

Tags: ajax, neo4j, reactjs, cypher

I have implemented Neo4j graph database using jquery. The following code retrieves the data as JSON. The data retrieval cypher query is defined in AUTO_COMPLETE_QUERY.

```
function bindAutocompleteSearch(){
    var ajaxRequest={};
    ajaxRequest["query"]=AUTO_COMPLETE_QUERY;
    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: NODE_URL,
         data: JSON.stringify(ajaxRequest),
         contentType: "application/json",
         accept:"application/json; charset=utf-8",            
         success: function (response, status, jqXHR) {              
         var res=JSON.parse(response) ;      
         var nameList=[];               
         //Get table columns        
         var columns=Object.keys(res.columns).length; 
         //Get table rows                 
         var rows=Object.keys(res.data).length;
         for(i=0;i<rows;i++){                       
                for(j=0;j<columns;j++){
                    nameList.push(res.data[i][j]);
            }
         }
         $("#inputTxt").autocomplete({
         source:nameList,                 
         autoFocus: true
         });              
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, status) {
         // error handler
    }
    });
}
```

How I can implement the same using react JS? I want to retrieve the data stored in graph database using react js through cypher query.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you start with React documentation.

There is example how to use React and jQuery together - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#updating-state

Comment: Is there a way to get a json file t react component without using jquery? via an AJAX call